# start up script with infinite loop as a root

Tags: startup, startup-applications

How can I start a script automatically at startup which includes an infinite loop as a root? The script basically restarts the vpn connection whenever it dies:

run.sh

```
while true; 
    do openvpn --config openvpn.ovpn --script-security 2 --up up.sh --down down.sh --up-restart && break; 
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define it as a [`systemd` service](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/). You script doesn't need to be a loop, systemd can be told to restart the service when it crashes, and run pre- and post-execution scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I defined it as a service and it is now working!! Amazing :)